# Is it possible to copy to clipboard as RTF in JS?

Tags: javascript, clipboard, rtf

I want to copy text as RTF, but Clipboard API seems not to support this format according to [THIS](https://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/#mandatory-data-types-x).

I wrote following function to copy the text in form of plain text (second arg) and rtf (first arg). Tried html, but doesn't work, MS Word just takes all RTF stuff as plain text.

```js
function copy(rtf, text) {
  function listener(e) {
    e.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", text);
    e.clipboardData.setData("text/html", rtf);
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  document.addEventListener("copy", listener);
  document.execCommand("copy");
  document.removeEventListener("copy", listener);
};
```

I have following types:

- text/plain
- text/uri-list
- text/csv
- text/html
- image/svg+xml
- application/xml, text/xml
- application/json

but there is no RTF. Is it possible to write my own type somehow?

Comment: Did you still find any solution? I have same issue and want to copy RTF to clipboard by JavaScript. I also tried with `navigator.clipboard` and with `https://clipboardjs.com/`, but did not succeed.

Comment: It seems impossible at this moment. The RTF is aged format and proprietary document file format with published specification developed by Microsoft Corporation.